# String manipulation In android for printing

Tags: android, string, android-bluetooth, spannablestring, android-print-framework

In my application need to send `String` to a printer, with structured String 
Like first line is bold and middle of the printing page.

After draw line and make three column
Item code  item        quantity
set items in each row

```
String line="_____________________________________________________________________"+"\n";
            String cl= "       <H1>Company Name(CLPPL) <H1>"+"\n";
print=line+Html.fromHtml(cl)+line;
```

I am trying Like above 
I am using Html but it is not working

Please Help Me how i can make this kind of the `String`

Thanks IN Advance

Answer (score 1):

Embedded html in Java code.Use StringBuilder class to append string one by one.
Use hint

> ```
>    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
> ```

```
     stringBuilder_month.append("<html><body>");
     stringBuilder_month.append("<font color="+"#413839"+"><h3 align="+"center"+"<b1>");
     stringBuilder_month.append("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
     stringBuilder_month.append("Your Heading</b1>");
     stringBuilder_month.append("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
     stringBuilder_month.append("</body></html>");
```

Add html tags as you required.You need to modify it according to your needs. This code will solve your problem

Comment: but how can i convert it in simple string

Comment: StringBuilder object is it self a string.Simply pass string builder object as your string.

Comment: but when i pass it on outputstream then getting error

Comment: Actually I was make use of this.make stringBuilder.toString();